# redraw method is not refreshing polar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, data-visualization

I have a similar problem like posted on [highchart chart redraw method is not refreshing the chart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16981158/7666076) but I am working with polar chart, so the solution given there is not solving my issue.

So, the code below is showing the highchart correctly, but doesn't refreshing data. Now I'm asking for advice/help how to solve it.

```
$(function() {

$.getJSON('wind_graph.php?callback=?', function(dataWind) {

 var direction = Wind_direction;

  var polarOptions = {
    chart: {
      polar: true,
      events : {
          load : function () {
              setInterval(function(){
                RefreshDataWind();
                }, 1000);
          }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Wind Direction'
    },
    pane: {
      startAngle: 0,
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    // the value axis
    xAxis: {
      tickInterval: 15,
      min: 0,
      max: 360,
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return this.value + '°';
        }
      }
    },

    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointStart: 0,
        pointInterval: 30,
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        },
      },
    }
  };

  // The polar chart
  $('#graph-1').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(polarOptions, {
    yAxis: {
      tickInterval: 5,
      min: 0,
      max: 25,
      visible: false
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Direction',
        data: [
          [0, 0],
          [direction, 20]
        ],
        lineColor: '#7cb5ec',
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        visible: true,
        lineWidth: 2,
        zIndex: 8,
      }
    ]
  }));

  function RefreshDataWind()
  {
    var chart = $('#graph-1').highcharts();

    $.getJSON('wind_graph.php?callback=?', function(dataWind)
    {
        var direction = Wind_direction;
        chart.redraw();
    }); 

    chart.redraw();
  }
});
});
```

To be more precise: if given Wind_direction value is equal to 0 (zero), then I need to display on chart the following "spline":

```
{
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'CentralCicrleCalmWind1',
        data: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        pointInterval: 30,
        pointStart: 0,
        lineColor: windLineColor,
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        lineWidth: windLineWidth,
        visible: showCentralCicrleCalmWind,
      }, {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'CentralCicrleCalmWind2',
        data: [2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5],
        pointInterval: 30,
        pointStart: 0,
        lineColor: windLineColor,
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        lineWidth: windLineWidth,
        visible: showCentralCicrleCalmWind,
      }
```

So as You can see, I have additional parameters like "showCentralCircleCalmWind" set to TRUE or FALSE depends on the given "Wind_direction" value and logic for this I have prepared at top of my code (not pasted here).
The thing what I need is:

1. Read value of variable in given JSON
2. Set variable "direction" at the begining of javascript code
3. Display the chart using higcharts library
4. Read the new value from JSON
5. Change the variable "direction" to the new value.
6. Display the new chart for a given value
7. Back to the point number 4...

Comment: the last one `chart.redraw();` is seems unnecessary. remove it . do you have any error in your browser console?

Comment: I don't have any error in browser console. Only Violation warnings about long runing JavaScirpt task took 369ms.
Maybe the jquery version should I change? Actually I'm using jquery 1.11.3

Comment: change to latest one and check.Also why this much time is taken?

Comment: Changed to 3.1.1.min and the Violation errors not showing again, but the refreshing is still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem may be helped by using the `setData()` function (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData).

In your example, I'd suggest the following:

```
function RefreshDataWind()
{
    var chart = $('#graph-1').highcharts();

    $.getJSON('wind_graph.php?callback=?', function(dataWind)
    {
        var direction = Wind_direction;
        chart.series[0].setData(direction);
        /* assuming "direction" to be an array like [1, 2, 3] */
    }); 

}
```

The following Highcharts demo shows you how this works: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-setdata/

Depending on the format of your "Wind_direction" variable, you may need to have a statement before `setData()` that explicitly makes it an array, since that's what the function is expecting.

I'd also suggest you remove the second instance of `chart.redraw()`, as the `setData()` makes that unnecessary.

I hope this is helpful for you!

Comment: Okay, we're going in the good way, but to be more precisly - I need to update the var direction value in the 5th row of my code, because my code is quite complicated than I've posted here. There is a few more data to plot on the same chart and they are depending on this variable.

Comment: So, your variable "Wind_direction" has data for more than one series in this chart?

Comment: No, the variable "Wind_direction" is used in more than one series (I have them aprox 20).
Also - I am rendering text on my chart with function chart.renderer.text() to display the current value of the "Wind_direction" variable and this renderer also should be to refresh.

Comment: You need to loop through the series/data and change what it should be changed. Don't update 'the variable', update the data/series properties. If you have custom text, then you need to change it manually via text.attr({text: 'new text'})